# Search bar in core data project

Tags: uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar, magicalrecord

I use core data with magical record and i'm try to filter data with a search bar in a table view.

I write two methods to get the number of rows and the name of the cells:

```
    -(int) dammiNumeroCercati:(NSString *)searchBar
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nome CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchBar];

    NSArray*arra = [Ricetta MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nome" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];


    return arra.count;
}
-(NSString*) dammiNomeRicettaCercata:(NSString *)searchBar mostrataNellaCella: (int) cella
{

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nome CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchBar];

    NSArray *arra = [Ricetta MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nome" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];
    Ricetta*ctn = arra[cella];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ctn.nome];
}
```

then i call this method inside the numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: inside an if cycle:

```
if (self.mySearchBar.isFirstResponder){

// the above methods

} else {
 // the normals methods to have all the data
}
```

somebody know where I'm wrong or if I miss somethings?

Comment: what is the problem? and how are u calling the above methods? like what arguments are u passing?

Comment: Even if it worked: Calling `MR_findAllSortedBy` again and again is extremely ineffective. You should look at NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: @ govi The problem is that the search bar doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`searchBar` is usually a `UISearchBar`, not a string.

You should use `searchBar.text` and process that in your methods.

Also, in your table view's datasource methods you have to make sure which table view is causing the callback, and then return the correct count/string. Usually this is checked by comparing pointers to the two tables (original table view and search results table view).

```
-(NSUInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
       numberOfRowsInSection:(NSUInteger)section {

   if (tableView == _tableView) {
      // return the usual row count
   }
   return [self dammiNumeroCercati:_searchBar.text];
}
```